# How do I get the text of a hyperlink (not the actual link) using selenium and python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

How do I get the TEXT of a hyperlink with selenium and python?

This is the html in question:

```
<a ng-href="/example/example2/" href="/example/example2/">NEEDED TEXT</a>
```

I already have the element of the 'a' tag and I am able to successfuly get the link by doing element.get_attribute("href").

But when I try to do element.text i am not able to get "NEEDED TEXT". What is the reason for this?

Comment: What is exactly happening when you invoke `element.text`?

Comment: It just returns an empty string ' ' when i do `element.text` . I ended up getting it to work with both `element.get_attribute('innerHTML')` and `element.get_attribute('text')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that there are no other elements within the `<a>` tag?
`element.text` should return the text.
You can also try `element.get_attribute('innerHTML')` and check whether it works.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally the `element.text` should work. If it doesn't, then you can try any of `element.get_attribute('innerHTML')` or `element.get_attribute('text')`. Note that the parameters to get_attribute is case sensitive.